# how does socat work to link two sockets together to create a port forwarded connection?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I'm trying to write a simple port forwarder. Say I have a service that is listening on localhost on 9999. It isn't accessible from outside the local system. However, I can forward this to 192.168.1.10 on port 9999 using this command:

socat -d TCP4:localhost:9999 TCP4:192.168.1.10:9999

Then I can just listen on 192.168.1.10 and reach the internal server. Of course I could use an ssh tunnel as well but for the sake of learning, I feel like writing my own non-ssh version.

My code isn't anything passed a simple c program that connects to the listener, then I open a connection to the remote ip. I tried to use recv and send but that isn't doing much. I'm trying to understand how I link them together to create this loop and handle EOF. What exactly happens here?

```
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] I socat by Gerhard Rieger and contributors - see www.dest-unreach.org
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] I This product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit. (http://www.openssl.org/)
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] I This product includes software written by Tim Hudson (tjh@cryptsoft.com)
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] N opening connection to AF=2 127.0.0.1:9999
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] I starting connect loop
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] I socket(2, 1, 6) -> 5
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 127.0.0.1:52769
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] N opening connection to AF=2 192.168.1.10:9999
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] I starting connect loop
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] I socket(2, 1, 6) -> 6
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 192.168.1.20:52770
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] I resolved and opened all sock addresses
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [6,6]
2023/11/03 19:59:58 socat[1164] I transferred 123 bytes from 5 to 6
2023/11/03 20:00:28 socat[1164] I transferred 4 bytes from 6 to 5
2023/11/03 20:35:01 socat[1164] I transferred 29 bytes from 5 to 6
2023/11/03 20:35:03 socat[1164] N socket 2 (fd 6) is at EOF
2023/11/03 20:35:03 socat[1164] I shutdown(5, 1)
2023/11/03 20:35:03 socat[1164] I transferred 29 bytes from 5 to 6
2023/11/03 20:35:03 socat[1164] E write(6, 0xa00020000, 29): Broken pipe
2023/11/03 20:35:03 socat[1164] N exit(1)
2023/11/03 20:35:03 socat[1164] I shutdown(5, 2)
2023/11/03 20:35:03 socat[1164] I shutdown(6, 2)
```

I tried reading the source for it but when I get to things like this:

```
#define XIO_GETRDFD(s) (((s)->tag==XIO_TAG_DUAL)?(s)->dual.stream[0]->fd:(s)->stream.fd)
#define XIO_GETWRFD(s) (((s)->tag==XIO_TAG_DUAL)?(s)->dual.stream[1]->fd:(((s)->stream.dtype&XIODATA_WRITEMASK)==XIOWRITE_2PIPE)?(s)->stream.para.exec.fdout:(((s)->stream.dtype&XIODATA_WRITEMASK)==XIOWRITE_PIPE)?(s)->stream.para.bipipe.fdout:(s)->stream.fd)
```

that I've never seen before and get lost, I need a bit of help understanding what is going on. And I've read some complicated stuff before, but not like that. So I'd rather ask on a high level, how this process works. How do I create a stream, do I need to fork any child processes of any kind? That's sort of what I am interested in finding out.

Tried understanding what the socat tool does.

Comment: In few words, socat does multiplexed I/O: it waits for event on both descriptors. When one of them becomes readable, socat reads data and writes it to another descriptor. All `xio` stuff is a wrapper for modularity and portability.

Comment: thanks. i did extra debugging and noticed there is a string of `select` being used which I did some reading on. However, how would I handle the EOF issue with enter being pressed on the client side not going through or hanging? I came across a linux multiplex server/client and all works except if I just press enter without anything before, it causes it to hang indefinitely.

Comment: `select()` still works but i'd recommend more convenient `poll` (POSIX) or `epoll` (Linux-specific) interface. I don't understand what is your EOF issue. When one peer closes connection, `select()` marks descriptor as readable and `recv()` returns 0, as in usuall stream socket communication. Your forwarder should close it's own connection to another peer. `poll()`/`epoll_wait()` also indicate POLLHUP/EPOLLHUP event.